# Use a getter setter in apex function - lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

In an apex class, I have a method that I use in a lightning component. 
In another function I put a value in a parameter, and I want to use this parameter in the method called by lightning :

```
public object__c num { get; set; } 
public String number {get; set;}
public void reNumber(){
   num = [SELECT number__c FROM object__c WHERE ...];
   number = num.number__c;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void getName(String id){
   String Name = '-' + number; //this line doesn't compile : I get "variable doesn't exist"
}
```

So I need to use the value `number` into the `getName` method, is there a way to retrieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Apex Server-Side Controller Overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm) says:

> Don't store component state in your controller. Store it in a
>   component's attribute instead.

So you will need to pass the `number` parameter from the client-side. Or for you case it looks like you can move the query into the `getName` method (or into a `static` method you call from it) if it is based on the `Id` parameter.

Not being able to reference controller instance variables is a core design decision to avoid needing mechanisms like the view state used in Visualforce that can compromise performance and add complexity. This is enforced by the requirement that `@AuraEnabled` methods must also be `static` and so are unable to reference controller instance variables.

(`@RemoteAction` methods and methods in `@Restresource` classes are also `static` and so behave similarly.)